# Añadir segue UICollectionView Cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitableview

Hay alguna forma de añadir un `segue` en un `UICollectionViewCell` como se hace en un `UITableViewCell`??

De momento tengo este código pero no me funciona

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    /*let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "TEST 1", message: "\(indexPath.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)*/

    self.selectedOfer = self.ofertas[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toOfertasSegue", sender: self)

    return true
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//Aqui puedes hacer el segue
    }
```

Esta función es la que es llamada cuando clicamos sobre una celda y así poder aplicar la lógica que creamos conveniente , que en tu caso sería hacer un segue

Comment: He llegado a esta respuesta porque está en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad. Creo que esta respuesta podría ser la solución al problema de OP, pero no estoy seguro. ¿Podrías añadir una pequeña descripción sobre por qué o cómo esta función resolvería el problema?

Comment: Ya esta actualizado el comentario